# htaccess Photoplog rewrite url

Tags: vbulletin

I am using vbulletin and installed photoplog and this is my  url:

```
https://www.mknexusonline.com/gallery/
```

and this is my category url

https://www.mknexusonline.com/gallery/index.php?n=1025

Rewrite url i want 
    https://www.mknexusonline.com/gallery/category

and this is my image url

https://www.mknexusonline.com/gallery/images/5/1_mk11-_scorpion-win.jpg

rewrite url like this    https://www.mknexusonline.com/gallery/categoryname/mk-scorpion-win.jpg

now the questions i want to rewrite my image url like this

the number 1027 is bu default after install photoplog

and this is already rewrite url see demo link
https://www.pentaxforums.com/gallery/  (its not my website)
https://www.pentaxforums.com/gallery/travel/  (this category rewrite i want like this )

and this image rewrite url
https://www.pentaxforums.com/gallery/photo-mexican-alebrijes-56660/ (i want like this )

Comment: rule i want like this 
https://www.mknexusonline.com/gallery/categoryname/filename
and the number 1027 i get by default this number after install photoplog

Comment: ok i have edited